# Welcome! instead of ¡Bienvenido! on es.stackoverflow.com

Tags: bug, localization, spanish-stackoverflow

I created a new account to take a look as new user to new responsive design. After the sign-up page, the right panel shows a "Welcome box". The problem is that the heading is in English instead of Spanish.

[image]

We are using traducir.win. It shows that the "Welcome!" string is already translated as `¡Bienvenido!`.

[image]

---

## Update 2018-10-01

Now the Welcome box heading says `Bienvenidos!` but it's grammatically wrong. IMNHO the correct is string is `¡Bienenvenido!` as it's shown on the traducir.win screenshot.

[image]

---

Related

- [Recuadro en panel de Stack Overflow Meta en español se muestra en inglés y no se encuentra en transifex](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3097/65)

Comment: @alexolut it's not the same Welcome box. This one is shown to new users on the main site rather than being shown to unsigned users on meta.

Comment: you’re probably right here, but I think the root of the issue is the same. Will wait for response from any of SO stuff.

Comment: It's the same box. Looks like SOes meta had the translated setting value, so I updated the value on SOes main to the same thing.

Comment: @AdamLear: Thank you but the text is wrong. It says `Bienvenidos!` but it should be `¡Bienvenido!`

Comment: @Rubén we went with the plural there to make it more inclusive. Otherwise, we're always assuming the visitor is male.

Comment: I added the missing character, though, my bad on copy/paste there.

Comment: @AdamLear Thanks. Note: There was a missing character (`¡`) and an extra character (`s`) :)

Comment: I defer to @g3rv4 on that. :)

Comment: @Rubén we went with the plural (the extra `s`) because otherwise Bienvenido assumes the visitor is a male. Bienvenidos doesn't assume the gender (well, it still kind of does, but that's how Spanish works). I'd be happy to toss a Bienvenide there.

Comment: @g3rv4 As you (the company) have clear that is a style decision, it's fine. So we could asume that `usuarios` should be  used instead of `usuario` and so on, right? In any case, the box is now in Spanish and that is a better than the previous state :)